JWT expired outof nowhere in express backend
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const SECRET_KEY = "qwerty@2025";

const generateToken = (userId) => {
  const userIdString = userId.toString(); // Convert ObjectId to string
  console.log("user id is:", userIdString);

  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: userIdString }, SECRET_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "1h",
  });
  console.log("Generated Token:", token);
  return token;
};

const decodeToken = async (token) => {
  try {
    console.log("The arrived token is :", token);
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
    console.log("Decoded Token:", decoded);
    const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    console.log(currentTimestamp, "the currenttimestamp");
    console.log(decoded.exp, "the token expiration timestamp");
    if (decoded.exp < currentTimestamp) {
      console.error("Token has expired");
      throw new Error("Token has expired");
    }
    return decoded;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
      console.error("Token has expired");
      // You could trigger a token refresh here if you implement that mechanism
    } else {
      console.error("Token verification failed:", error.message);
    }
    return null;
  }
};

const getUserFromToken = async (token) => {
  try {
    const decodedToken = await decodeToken(token);
    console.log("Decoded Token:", decodedToken);

    // Check if the decodedToken is valid and has the userId
    if (!decodedToken || !decodedToken.userId) {
      throw new Error("UserID is undefined or null");
    }

    console.log("Parsed UserID from token:", decodedToken.userId);
    return decodedToken.userId;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error getting user from token:", error.message);
    throw new Error("Invalid token");
  }
};

module.exports = { generateToken, getUserFromToken };


is the code
Just after generating token also the token expired error is occuring , why is it happening outof no where? TokenExpiredError is happening , even though the token is generated within 2 minutes , why is it so ? What wrong I must be doing ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
